# XML de servidor externo

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml

estoy generando un archivo html que trae datos de un xml pero si no esta dentro del servidor mio no lo muestra y yo necesito que lo traiga de un servidor externo ya que va a ser adminsitrado de afuera. Cual es el error? el archivo es noticias.xml ese necesito que venga de un servidor externo.

Gracias

Lo que hago es un button que tiene onclick="loadXMLDoc() y en una tabla con id="table" que los liste.

El problema seguramente esta en el siguiente script:

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "noticias.xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="NoticiaFoto";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
  for (i = 0; i " +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITULO")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("FOTO")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que estas teniendo un problema de CORS. es decir que el servidor de donde deseas obtener el xml no   permite request de otros dominios, no se podria controlar desde el codigo cliente, deberia configurarse en el servidor.

tienes algun mensaje de error?

puedes revisar este tema

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272611/make-cors-ajax-requests-using-xmlhttprequest

Comment: Este error me da:

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.dominioexterno.com/xml/rss.xml. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://midominio.com.ar' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: usa las herramientas del navegador para revisar los HEADERS que trae la respuesta del servidor. pegalos aqui, deberia traer algo asi Access-Control-Allow-Origin si permite request de otros sitios

Comment: en resumen es una cuestion de seguridad del navegador/js, no puedes hacer request de un dominio A a un dominio B ,a  menos que el dominio B lo permita a traves de los headers.

Comment: puedes intentar esto antes de enviar el request

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.dominioexterno.com/xml/rss.xml. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://midominio.com.ar' is therefore not allowed access.